# mismatched types 'std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock' and 'std::chrono::_V2::system_clock'

Tags: c++, mingw-w64, timing, c++-chrono

I'm trying to build my program in **mingw64** (GCC v11.2). I have the following *struct*:

In a header file:

```
struct Timer
{
    std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::steady_clock > start;
    std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::steady_clock > end;

    Timer( );
    ~Timer( );
};
```

In a source file:

```
util::Timer::Timer( )
: start( std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now( ) )
{
}

util::Timer::~Timer( )
{
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now( );
    std::chrono::duration< double, std::milli > duration_ms { end - start };
    std::clog << "\nTimer took " << duration_ms.count( ) << " ms\n";
}
```

But this happens:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >::time_point(std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::time_point)'
    8 | : start( std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now( ) )
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from pch.h:23:
c:\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\chrono:871:21: note: candidate: 'template<class _Dur2, class> constexpr std::chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Dur>::time_point(const std::chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Dur2>&) [with _Dur2 = _Dur2; <template-parameter-2-2> = <template-parameter-1-2>; _Clock = std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock; _Dur = std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> >]'
  871 |           constexpr time_point(const time_point<clock, _Dur2>& __t)
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\chrono:871:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Util.cpp:8:3: note:   mismatched types 'std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock' and 'std::chrono::_V2::system_clock'
    8 | : start( std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now( ) )
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Comment: `std::chrono::steady_clock` != `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` (necessarily).  You can't mix and match them like that.

Comment: @Paul Sanders Someone used this code in MSVC++ and it compiled. Is the implementation of mingw64 different from that of MSVC?

Comment: As @PaulSanders says compiler is right.  However the code compiles in clang (with libc++) and MSVC live - https://godbolt.org/z/ddb5Mxcv9

Comment: `high_resolution_clock` can be the same clock as `steady_clock`, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @Marshall Clow So do you mean that my `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now( )` uses `std::chrono::system_clock` and I should declare `start` and `end` with `std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::system_clock >` type?

Comment: `high_resolution_clock` is an alias for `steady_clock` or `system_clock`.  Which it is is implementation defined and can change even from version to version.

Comment: Why not change `start` and `end` to be `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>`? Or use `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`? Basically, don't mix them

Comment: See the notes here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the information provided in the comments, I came up with the following solution:

In the header file:

```
struct Timer
{
    std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::steady_clock > start;
    std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::steady_clock > end;

    Timer( );
    ~Timer( );
};
```

In the source file:

```
util::Timer::Timer( )
: start( std::chrono::steady_clock::now( ) )
{
}

util::Timer::~Timer( )
{
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now( );
    std::clog << "\nTimer took " << std::chrono::duration< double, std::milli >( end - start ).count( ) << " ms\n";
}
```

So in short, I switched from `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now( )` to `std::chrono::steady_clock::now( )` because `high_resolution_clock` has different implementations on different compilers according to [high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock).
 On some of them it returns `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>` and in some others it returns `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>`. And that caused problems for me.

*A note from cppreference:*

> #### Notes
>
> The high_resolution_clock is not implemented consistently across different standard library implementations, and its use should be avoided. It is often just an alias for std::chrono::steady_clock or std::chrono::system_clock, but which one it is depends on the library or configuration. When it is a system_clock, it is not monotonic (e.g., the time can go backwards). For example, for gcc's libstdc++ it is system_clock, for MSVC it is steady_clock, and for clang's libc++ it depends on configuration.
>
> Generally one should just use std::chrono::steady_clock or std::chrono::system_clock directly instead of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock: use steady_clock for duration measurements, and system_clock for wall-clock time.

Comment: It would be good to mark this as your own answer.